# New (but 2016) Razer keyboard backlight cycles

Tags: keyboard, backlight

I get my new-but-old Razer keyboard (Blackwidow Ultimate 2016) out of the box.
(old Kubuntu, can't update or install stuff)

And keyboard works, but the back-light annoyingly goes on and off every few seconds.

I have no windows box to try and set it up. Any suggestions? And even if I do, will the setup hold or needs to be done on every reboot?

Thanks, Joseph

Comment: Do you use the openrazer driver ? which version ? Do you have the daemon running ? Do you need gaming mode or only stable backlights ?

Comment: I can't install anything at the moment. I just want the damn light to be steady (but not off completly, which I can control with FN F11 and F12). Thanks!

Comment: woo! If you get no dedicated driver installed then there is just no way for your system to command to the lights. Only the firmware can. Does blinking also concern the standard (caps-lock/num-lock) leds ? If yes then I'd first suspect a loose USB cable. Does blinking also happen when under the command of the BIOS ?

Comment: I am aware I can't do anything under Linux (thank you so much, Razer). I mostly need to know that if I do get to a friends home and able to change using a windows box it will hold from that point on...

Comment: Please first answer to my questions above. (standard leds & BIOS). Then IF its a firmware problem then it could possibly be upgrade it from another system. But I would first suspect a USB connection problem.